# Column That Is A Ratio of Other Unique Values On Matching Dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I have a database that is a combination of ticker symbols, dates, and their price on that date.

A sample looks like this:

[image]

What I need to do is create a new table that calculates the ratio between the values for `DEM` and `AUS` when they have the same dates.

So, the example output might look like this:

[image]

With the following starter code, what query could I use to create the desired results?

```
CREATE TABLE test(
DT DATE,
Ticker varchar(10),
Price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(
'1-01-2020', 'DEM', 25),
('1-02-2020', 'DEM', 24),
('1-03-2020', 'DEM', 26),
('1-04-2020', 'DEM', 25),
('1-01-2020', 'AUS', 25),
('1-03-2020', 'AUS', 20),
('1-04-2020', 'AUS', 25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `join`

```
select td.dt, td.price / ta.price as value
from test td join
     test ta
     on td.date = ta.date 
where td.ticker = 'DEM' and ta.ticker = 'AUS';
```

Comment: `cast(td.date as date) = cast(ta.date as date)` isn't needed in `on` clause of join?

Comment: @timnavigate . . . I don't see why that would be necessary.

Comment: truly! because we make a join of the table to itself, and the column type is date - sorry I'm not paying attention.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel . . . You should be aware that this is probably the fastest solution, particularly if you have an index on the date column.  Aggregation is more flexible, but you have a specific need here with one row per date/ticker combo and you only want matches.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you.   This solution works, but with the caveat that it doesn't generate a name  for the values created.  Is there a way to do this, so that each row of the resulting value has a symbol associated with it, like `RATIO_VAL` or something like that?

Comment: @JonathanBechtel . . . You would do that as you would name any column, using `as` to assign a column alias.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel are you really convinced that a self join creating a resultset of nxn rows and then filtering is faster than filtering first on the n rows of the table and then aggregating?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no duplicate tickers in the same date, you can `GROUP BY` date and then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 'DA-RATIO' Name,
       DT,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Ticker = 'DEM' THEN Price END) /
       MAX(CASE WHEN Ticker = 'AUS' THEN Price END) VALUE
FROM test
WHERE Ticker IN ('DEM', 'AUS')
GROUP BY DT
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f59c3913c59319ee486db571b595cdf).
Results:

```
> Name     | DT         | VALUE
> :------- | :--------- | ----:
> DA-RATIO | 2020-01-01 |     1
> DA-RATIO | 2020-01-03 |   1.3
> DA-RATIO | 2020-01-04 |     1
```